# How to stop Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created the start alarm as shown below

```
 public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   // Restart service every 30 seconds
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 5;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

I crate this for stop alarm and i call it from main activity.Manifest  i think is ok...Work repeat but no stop!!!

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(this,MyScheduleReceiver.class));

}

public void StopRepeat(View view) {

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(this,MyStopReceiver.class));   

}

 public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Toast.makeText(context, "Repeat service!.",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  public class MyStopReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  // Restart service every 30 seconds
  private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 5;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent istop = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, istop,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

      service.cancel(pending);
```

But the service is not stopping. What might be the issue?Thanks.

Comment: You can restart your device. (Unless you have created a `BOOT_COMPLETE` BroadcastReceiver, but you can disable this too.)

Comment: have u <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> put in Manifest file

Comment: Yes i have boot completed....

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to restart your device. (If you created a `BOOT_COMPLETED` listener just remove it for now.)

You can also cancel an alarm by passing the PendingIntent you used to create the alarm to [`AlarmManager#cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29). You have already written the code to do this, *but* do you have a Button with the XML attribute `android:onClick="StopRepeat"` in `setup.xml`? Did you click it?

---

**Solution**
We eventually discovered you had a mistake in your Manifest file, so `MyStopServiceReceiver` was never called...

Comment: yes i have button stop...i make restart,remove boot completed...but nothing...no stop repeat!!

Comment: Only with restart device...stoped!

Comment: Good, you are probably starting the alarm in more than one place... Do you start an alarm in MyScheduleReceiver?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why the alarm didn't stop... Please post `setup.xml`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the calendar?I must remove it?Change method?

Comment: Setup.xml is only one button stop onClick="StopRepeat" and i call onStop onDestroy...

Comment: I think i must use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733761/how-to-cancel-alarmmanager-on-a-scheduled-time?rq=1)

Comment: You are already using the code in that link. Are all of your receivers in one file or separate files? Could you post your manifest file in your question?

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @Sam